# Python scripts single instance does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using [this file from tendo](https://github.com/pycontribs/tendo/blob/master/tendo/singleton.py) to be able to create a single instance for a script. Using Python 2.7

In a `main.py` script I am add a code line like this:

```
sgl_ins = singleton.SingleInstance()
.. main.py logic code ...
```

It creates the .lock file but the thing is that it is throwing me an error when the app logic finishes, more precisely when it reaches this part in the `singleton.py` code

```
try:
           if sys.platform == 'win32':
               if hasattr(self, 'fd'):
                   os.close(self.fd)
            os.unlink(self.lockfile)
```

in the console I get

> [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: ...

So it is weird because it should close the file that had been locked but it looks like when it tries to close it can not do it.

There is no other app or script instance running at the same time. I am running it into a Windows env the user has all permissions granted.

Any suggestion or comment?

Comment: I also think that some windows process might be locking that file. you can use the built-in Resource Monitor or write a test script.

Comment: If you have the file opened in your IDE or Editor another process is using it, also if the program failed unexpectedly (for example by just killing its process) the lock file can be there from an earlier run.

Comment: @LinFelix, thanks for answering.. the script runs in a separete machine so no IDE nor editor is using it.

Comment: @MEdwin Thanks for answering, I quite sure that there is not other process using it. Anyway I´ll double check that. Regarding Resource Monitor you refer to this? http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html.

Comment: I cant click that link at work. But there are actually lots of alternatives. I use LockHunter myself. See these answers : https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows.